# Solutions containing TypeScript keep loading eternally, using VS2013

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, visual-studio, typescript

I'm on Visual Studio 2013, when I open any solution containing TypeScript, fleshed out or barebone, I get this:

[image]

*(names removed for confidentiality reasons)*

Very soon that leads to this (likely very well known) message:

[image]

Ultimately I can only close the session by killing the specific process.

I have requested VS2015, but that requires an approvement process which will take a while. In the meantime I would prefer to get VS2013 working, especially since VS2015 isn't garantueed to fix it (it *should*, but I don't know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would prefer to get VS2013 working, especially since VS2015 isn't guaranteed to fix it (it should, but I don't know)

Bad news its been reported to Microsoft various times and doesn't look like it will be fixed:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/802212/vs-hang-when-debugging-typescript-file (still active, yet is 3 years old)

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1057036/visual-studio-hangs-in-typescript-debugger (closed 3 years ago)

Good news it has been fixed in Visual Studio 2015 as per https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1999

If you have any issues remove Glimpse, Glimpse.AspNet and Glimpse.Mvc packages.

Also see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4528, where the solution is to [install TypeScript 1.5.4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_devresources)

> I have requested VS2015, but that requires an approvement process which will take a while.

If you dont have access to MSDN subscription to download Pro or Enterprise editions, simply download the Community Edition in the mean time [which has most of the features](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx).

Comment: Downloading Community in a commercial environment is a very big no no. Bureaucracy has done it's thing and delivered VS2015, it doesn't seem to have the issue.

Comment: You're right, I just didn't know if this annoying issue was affecting your work or a personal project. Glad it's resolved for your works particular project with VS2015, cheers